# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.client.methods.RequestBuilder.post

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.http.client.methods.RequestBuilder.post(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/RequestBuilder;
>     at
>   org.eclipse.rdf4j.http.client.SesameSession.getQueryMethod(SesameSession.java:701)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.rdf4j.http.client.SparqlSession.sendTupleQuery(SparqlSession.java:380)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.rdf4j.repository.http.HTTPTupleQuery.evaluate(HTTPTupleQuery.java:49)
>     at
>   com.cmclinnovations.jps.kb.ontokin.SparqlEndpoint.queryRepository(SparqlEndpoint.java:92)
>     at
>   com.cmclinnovations.jps.kb.ontokin.SparqlEndpoint.main(SparqlEndpoint.java:49)

While trying to query an RDF4J triple store using the following code, I experienced the above issue.

```
    try {
        Repository repo = new HTTPRepository(serverURL, repositoryID);
        repo.initialize();
        RepositoryConnection con = repo.getConnection();
        try {
            System.out.println("QueryString:\n"+queryString);
            // Export all statements in the context to System.out, in RDF/XML format
            TupleQuery queryResult = con.prepareTupleQuery(queryString);
            // A QueryResult is also an AutoCloseable resource, so make sure it gets
            // closed when done.
            try (TupleQueryResult result = queryResult.evaluate()) {
                json = getResultInJson(json, result);
            }finally{
                // Before our program exits, make sure the database is properly shut down.
                repo.shutDown();
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            logger.error("Exception occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new OntoException("Exception occurred.");
        } finally {
            logger.info("Successfully performed query");
            con.close();
        }
    } catch (RDF4JException e) {
        logger.error("RDF4JException occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new OntoException("RDF4JException occurred.");
    }
```

For HTTPClient, I've put the following dependency in the pom file of my project.

```
    <!-- Use Apache HttpClient as HTTP Client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError` usally occurs if you have incompatible jar files in your classpath. Check the compatibility of `RDF4J` and `httpclient`

Comment: Also it's weird to put a `logger.info("Successfully performed query");` in your `finally` block, given that it will be executed if an exception is raised.

Comment: @Vincz777 Thanks for your comment. It has been changed as follows:  
 finally {
    con.close();
    logger.info("The connection has been closed successfully.");
   }

Comment: @Jens I'm trying with different versions of httpclient. I will let you know if the issue disappears.

Comment: What RDF4J version do you use?

Comment: @m4gic I am using <rdf4j.version>2.0</rdf4j.version>.

Comment: If you check the [dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.rdf4j/rdf4j/2.0), you Will see that 4.5.2 is the right httpclient version

Comment: @m4gic many thanks for the link to the dependencies. It works with httpclient version 4.5.2. I updated it as follows:                                                                             
                <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
   <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
   <version>4.5.2</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Faced with similar problem on apache **httpclient5 5.2.1**. In my spring boot application it uses **wrong** versions (**5.1.5**) of its transitive dependencies (**httpcore5** and **httpcore5-h2**)  which has different methods and everything crashes. Maybe something wrong with parent xml because in clean new application dependencies are correct. Solved the problem by manually specifying the correct version (**5.2**) of **httpcore5** and **httpcore5-h2** dependencies in my project pom.xml.